# Facebook login email

Tags: facebook, authentication

Facebook stopped give me email. I've checked facebook developer console and everything looks fine. This is how I'm requesting email:

`graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)
profile = graph.get_object("me", fields='email,first_name,last_name,gender,birthday,picture,cover')`

Update:
my grants on facebook
[image: Facebook grants]

Comment: Did the user grant email permission? And is the users email address verified by them? And do they even have one?

Comment: I'm using my own account, it worked fine before.

Comment: That didn't answer any of my questions

Comment: I don't know how to check grant email permission, but I'm doing successful FB login on sites. But some of them returning error "no email"

Answer (score 0):

Seems like facebook just stopped sharing emails.